# how to retrieve data from a table using Foreign Key

Tags: sql-server-2005

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get a record of one fields and also of the Foriegn Key](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4551/get-a-record-of-one-fields-and-also-of-the-foriegn-key)

I have 2 tables

1. CountryMaster(CountryID,CountryName)
2. StateMaster(StateId,StateName,CountryId)

I want such a query that when i have a CountryName i can retrieve records from StateMaster.
Example:If i have a CountryName:India in CountryMaster and has countryID=1,then i should be able to get all the StateName from StateMaster with the CountryID=1.

```
Select StateName from StateMaster where CountryID='1'
```

I dont want to use CountryID this way as in above Query rather i have only CountryName and want to get record on that.

Comment: not quite a duplicate I think but perhaps too basic for this site? answer = `select statename from statemaster where countryid=(select countryid from countryname where countryname='India')` or similar with a `join`

Comment: First off, fellas, if you'll flag "duplicate accounts" so that we mods see them (we don't see every question posted on the site, alas) and secondly, we've already decided this site is not for "basic SQL query questions", they belong on [so].